# How to install python-docx at Ubuntu?

Tags: python

I have Ubuntu 19.04 without PIP.
Typically, I installed modules for Python using `sudo apt-get install 'module'`, but it doesn't work for *docx*(or *python-docx*).

Answer (score 1):

Simply download https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/83/c66a1934ed5ed8ab1dbb9931f1779079f8bca0f6bbc5793c06c4b5e7d671/python-docx-0.8.10.tar.gz (or a later version found at https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/#files)

Then un-tar it with `tar -x`, (or `python -mtarfile -e python-docx-0.8.10.tar.gz python-docx`).

Finally change directory to where you extracted it and run `python setup.py install`

Note that you will have to ensure that the dependencies are met first, at the time of writing they are:

- behave>=1.2.3
- flake8>=2.0
- lxml>=3.1.0
- mock>=1.0.1
- pyparsing>=2.0.1
- pytest>=2.5

But the latest will be in the requirements.txt file within the tar file.